Keycloak session limit with auto-logout
I'm developing a Spring Boot application with an Angular frontend, and I'm using Keycloak for authentication and authorization. The application relies on Server-Sent Events (SSE) for real-time information transfer.
To ensure that users can only be logged in from one device at a time, I have configured Keycloak's authentication flow to "Terminate oldest session". However, I've encountered the following issues:

Token Persistence: When a user logs in from a new device, Keycloak terminates the session on the previous device, but the JWT token remains valid. The user can continue to work in the application until they manually refresh the page, at which point they are logged out. This behavior is not ideal as I want the user to be automatically logged out from the previous device.

SSE Connection Issues: With multiple active logins, the SSE connection can become problematic. Ideally, each user should only have one active connection.


One workaround I found is to constantly ping Keycloak to check the user's session, but this approach seems inefficient and resource-intensive, especially with multiple users:
https://onyalioscar.medium.com/implementing-user-single-session-with-automatic-log-out-using-keycloak-java-spring-boot-and-ef23b0804417
How can I ensure that when a user logs in from a new device, it is automatically logged out from the previous device without the need for a manual refresh?

You have to perform long polling like 30s using the approach you have mentioned, which is the easiest method to handle the problem and the long duration eases the load on the server.
But as far as I know, when the user makes an API call using an expired JWT token, the API will give you a 401 Unauthorized error.
If the JWT token is valid, then validate the session also, then make the API throw 401 error
You can use angular interceptors to check for this error and logout off the application, hence deleting the JWT token also.

The point would be to log out before sending any request, not just when you try to do something in the app. Because for some reason, the SSE connection is still alive on the previous device until I log out and then it disconnects from both devices, causing further problems. Maybe it would be sufficient if it just logged out from the previous device when trying to send a request, but then I have to change the SSE logic, which I'm not quite familiar with yet unfortunately...
